# Labels placed incorrectly

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pinescript. My intention is on a 30 Min to place labels at the top of bar every "interval". For different interval values the behaviour seems to be different with some anamolay. I am not able to understand the execution process of pinescript. Below is the code.
interval is the variable that have values of 10 , 11 , 12. So place labels at every 10th,11th or 12 th bar . Starting with the 6th bar.

```
study(title="BarIdx_trial",overlay=true)
txt=""
lable_count=1
interval = 10
for x=6 to bar_index by interval
    txt := "barindex:"+tostring(bar_index)+"\n x:"+tostring(x)+"\nlow:"+tostring(low[x])+"\nLbl#:"+tostring(lable_count)
    label.new(bar_index-x, high+tr, txt)
    lable_count := lable_count + 1
    \\ Break the for loop when the label is placed at the oldest set of bars.
    if (bar_index-x < interval)
        break
```

**For interval value 10 . Towards the oldest bar of the chart some labels are not placed at all.**
[image]

**It is fine at the newest set of bars.**
[image]

**For interval value 11. It seems fine through out the chart.**
[image]

[image]

**For interval 12. Oldest bars seem to be fine**
[image]

**Again there is a anamoly at the newest set of bars. The labels are overlapped, actually they should have not got created itself.**
[image]

Any help will help in improving my understanding of pinescript and its execution model. I googled as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some strange things can happen with lines and labels when the maximum is exceeded. Firstly make sure that you have the `study()` parameter `max_labels_count = 500`.

Secondly I recommend using a `var label[]` array so that you can limit the total number of labels. Once the array size reaches the max number of labels you can manually delete the oldest one keeping the total number of labels on the chart below the set maximum.

Lastly it would be best to add a single new label every time your interval occurs rather than work backwards every bar to put labels on the whole chart. e.g

```
if (bar_index - 6) % interval == 0
     label.new(.....)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on your answer, I was able to realize that I have been unnecessarily using the for loop when it was necessary. I have used the if condition clause. That has helped me.